# Changing colour of placed object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

On my artboard I have a floral image which I placed as a png and then did image trace.  I then want to add some wording which is currently in an .ai file.  If I place the .ai file with the wording on to the artboard with the floral image, can I then edit the colour of the wording in the placed ai. file? Or does it need to be placed in a different format?  I want to sample colour from the floral image with the eyedropper tool.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly....

- File A - Image trace of floral pattern
- File B - Text

If you use `File > Place` from the menu to "place" File B in File A, then **no** you won't be able to alter the text. Placed files are *links* and links can't be directly edited in Illustrator.

You would either need to *embed* the placed file (via the Links Panel) to edit it, or copy/paste from File B to File A to have editable text.

Once a link is embedded, it becomes part of that actual file and is no longer associated with any external file. So, if you were to Place, then embed File B, the text is then part of File A and not a link at all.